# Should I use cluster for every route in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using the cluster module to fork my application in my `index.js` (which is the main file in my application/root directory of my website). Now my app contains many routes. Should I include the cluster code to wrap all my route files?

For e.g.

Consider my `index.js` file

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if(cluster.isMaster)
{
   cluster.fork();
   cluster.fork();

   cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) 
   {
      console.error('disconnect!');
      cluster.fork();
   });
}
else
{ 
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   app.get('/',function(req,res){
      //application logic goes here
   });
   var route1 = require('./route1.js');
   app.route('/route1',route1);
   app.listen(80);
}
```

So ,in my `route1.js` file, should I wrap it around the **cluster-code** just as I did around my `index.js` file or it's not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Your clusters are the ones who are receiving the http request in the end. They have to know what code, each cluster has to run based on the route. The way you have done it is already correct. If you are taking your project on production you might consider using a process manager like [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)